# Значения umask

Tags: ubuntu

Доброго времени суток! Объясните пожалуйста, какие значения что содержат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо внимательно прочитать текст по [ссылке](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=umask&category=1&russian=0).Так же надо пройтись по ссылкам в этой статье и прочитать про chmod и umask(2).Если что-то будет не понятно - спрашивайте более предметно.